# Cocos2d-x (4.0) - Integer pixel scaling

Tags: c++, opengl, cocos2d-x

I'm just starting with Cocos2d and I'm struggling to get screen scaling right: I have a glview with design resolution of 160x144 pixels, and I want to be able to scale this window up in integer multiples. The issue is that all assets on screen gets scaled using some sort of bilinear filter, really messing up the game overall look... Below all I've in my code now:

```
// Set the design resolution
glview->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height, ResolutionPolicy::SHOW_ALL);
glview->setFrameSize(designResolutionSize.width * SCALE_FACTOR, designResolutionSize.height * SCALE_FACTOR);
```

where SCALE_FACTOR can be 2, 4, 8...

Does anybody have any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you are better off cleaning your own mess. I found a solution for my issue, which in a firts glance might look like too extreme, but that works perfectly for my needs.
Simply change the constructor of Texture2D (@CCTexture2D.cpp) to disable anti-aliasing globally.

```
Texture2D::Texture2D()
: _pixelFormat(backend::PixelFormat::DEFAULT)
, _pixelsWide(0)
, _pixelsHigh(0)
, _maxS(0.0)
, _maxT(0.0)
, _hasPremultipliedAlpha(false)
, _hasMipmaps(false)
, _antialiasEnabled(false)  // <<< CHANGE HERE!
, _ninePatchInfo(nullptr)
, _valid(true)
, _alphaTexture(nullptr)
{
    backend::TextureDescriptor textureDescriptor;
    textureDescriptor.textureFormat = PixelFormat::NONE;
    _texture = static_cast<backend::Texture2DBackend*>(backend::Device::getInstance()->newTexture(textureDescriptor));
}
```

Here how it looks like:

[image: Antialiasing on/off]